# Add Extension for PHP to ctags

Tags: ctags

I'm trying to add ".inc" as an extension for PHP with ctags. I must be misinterpretting something in the manual. In my attempts to add the extension, I am running:

```
ctags --langmap=PHP:+.inc
```

The response given is:

```
ctags: No files specified. Try "ctags --help".
```

What am I missing? Do I need to specify some config file? FYi, I am running Exuberant Ctags 5.8 on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Answer (score 2):

To find out the current language-mappings, run `ctags --verbose`. This will list the default language-mappings and at the end of the output one can find additional configuration-results from all (possible) config-files.

As for your personal config-file: `~/.ctags` is the default one. It is also possible to have local config-files (`./.ctags`) in any working/project-directory.

Once a working command-line for ctags was found, add those additional parameters line by line to the preferred config-file. Here some example (including the answer from *jrwren*):

```
--langmap=PHP:+.inc.module
--langmap=Sh:+.csh
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running the right ctags. OSX ships with /usr/bin/ctags which is NOT Exuberant.

I tried what you wrote and it worked perfectly with a brew installed ctags.

```
/usr/local/bin/ctags -R --langmap=PHP:+.inc .
```